The method of temporarily storing records in a form and then transferring them to the main table in Laravel
I have a form in Laravel to record company meeting decisions, in which I have general meeting information such as the date, time of the meeting, meeting topic, the name of the chairman of the meeting, and the approvals of the meeting, which I want to save row by row in a temporary table by pressing the add button. And after pressing the final registration button in the form, I send the information to the main table in the database, is the method of transferring the information to the temporary table and then sending it to the main table correct? What is the standard procedure for this?

You haven't explained anything about why you want to use a temporary table. Did you try searching for tutorials on how to save form data to a DB?  Did you find any that use this approach?

The reason is that I have a series of common fields in the form, and to increase the speed, I want to insert the common fields (meeting details) once and after entering each approval, transfer the meeting together with the common fields to the main table at once.

Like choosing a food menu, you first choose the food items such as drinks, desserts, etc. and see them in a table, after reviewing and making sure, you register the request.

"to increase the speed" - I don't see how this would increase speed. "after reviewing and making sure" - OK so you want a 2-step process with a "review subission" stage, that make sense (though that is definitely not faster than not having a review stage). Usually that would be done with the session, not a temp table.  Write each step of progress to the session, at the end write session to your DB.  This way you don't have to delete the temp table contents if the user does not complete the process.

@Don'tPanic exactly. like a shoping cart.
